# convert a SQL update statement to a LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq, t-sql, entity-framework-6

Without writing an entire foreach loop is there a way to do a Update/Set in LINQ to Entities?
Using EF 6.x

Simple update query:

```
UPDATE stop_detail 
SET cap_unique_id = b.Delivery_Location_Id 
FROM order_detail b 
WHERE Stop_Detail.CAP_Unique_Id IS NULL AND ((b.customer_id = 20 OR b.customer_id = 291)  AND b.id = stop_detail.order_detail_id AND stop_type = 1)
```

all the context name are the same.
I normally end up writing about 30 lines of C# code to do this and I know there has to be a better way!

Comment: Well in EntityFramework default way of updating entities is to query your target set and then modify queried entities in a **loop** and then call the `SaveChanges`. Unless you use a third party library this is the standard procedure of updating database. And it shouldn't be 30 lines of code. In theory `query.ToList()` 1 line. foreach 2 line (or you can use `list.Foreach(t=> ...)` for 1 liner) and then calling `SaveChanges` 1 line ..

Comment: thank you....that is how I have been doing it...just wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: I was exaggerating about the 30 lines, but you know what I mean...thanks for the response Eldar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you *can* and whether you *should* are two different things.

Here's how you *can*.

Example from [EF6 Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql)

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
        "UPDATE dbo.Blogs SET Name = 'Another Name' WHERE BlogId = 1");
}
```

Hint: you probably *shouldn't*